# React conditional styling not working on first run

Tags: reactjs

This is the button that I am trying to style. I have set the opacity and pointer events to the condition that a checkbox is checked. The problem is that the first time you go on the page like if I refreshed the page, the opacity is set to 100% when it should be 50% and pointerEvents is set to auto when it should be none. Once I check and uncheck the box, everything works the way it should but once I refresh it goes back to 100% and auto when no box is checked.

```
<TrashButton opacity={mappingTableSelected.length === 0 ? '50%' : '100%'} style={{background: "#EE6C4d", display: mappingTableData.length === 0 ? "none" : "block", width: "30px", marginTop: "5px", pointerEvents: mappingTableSelected.length === 0 ? "none" : "auto", backgroundColor: "#e64e58"}} onClick={(e) => { e.preventDefault(); handleDeleteMapping() }} ><MdIcons.MdDelete size={20} /></TrashButton>
```

[image]

Comment: You forgot to include the code. Image is not a code

Comment: The most important part is how you assign this `mappingTableSelected`, not the button itself